# Error: ENOENT no such file or directory. When doing a get from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I get the following error when navigating to my localhost/games.html file.

```
GET /api/games 404 - 145
Error: ENOENT no such file or directory, stat C:\Users\rodos\Documents\Final\app\public\index.html
at Error (native)
```

I can POST and DELETE though, because after adding a game all of them are displayed. So the only problem is when you get into the page.

Have searched thoroughly on my code, but cant find the error on the GET operation. I'll add it in case you can find it.

```
function getGames(res) {
Game.find(function (err, games) {

    // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }

    res.json(games); // return all games in JSON format
});
}
;

module.exports = function (app) {

//GAMES
app.get('/api/games', function (req, res) {
    // use mongoose to get all games in the database
    getGames(res);
});
```

Appreciate all help I can get.

Comment: _"nothing after res.send(err) will execute"_. Yes it will!

Comment: Calling `res.send()` doesn't miraculously stop the rest of the code in the function from running.

Comment: @robertklep But how does that screws up the GET?

Comment: I'm not answering your question, I'm commenting on a comment in your code that's incorrect :D